# Jquery is not working for menu. When i select a particular list in a menu its not getting active

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

```
  <ul>
    <li class="active" ><a href="home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="about">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="login">Your Account</a></li>       
    <li><a href="logout"> Logout</a></li>

    </ul>
</div>
```

[HTML and Jquery code][1]https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASdUG.png

[html page output][2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDGK7.png

Comment: Paste your coding content here.

Comment: Please paste your code here, so that we can test it on our side & could be able to modify the code.

Comment: i'm unable to paste the code now

Comment: where you trying to add?

Comment: When i try to paste the code i face problem with the code alignment in stack over flow that's y i posted  image

Comment: i have posted the code somebody help me. since my code has bootstrap classes, stack overflow doesn't allow me to post here. for the bootstrap classes please refer the image

Comment: My jquery code
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("li").click(function() {
        $("li").removeClass("active");
       $(this).addClass("active");     
    });
});
</script>

Comment: i found that if i doesn't have the href link the active class is working fine. if i have a href link clicking on it takes to another page and jquery is not working. someone kindly help me how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Might be problem is in ordering the css and js.See the below code and try it, let me know if it is helpfull to you .

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I tried but its still not working. Is there any problem with the code?

Comment: provide fiddle , so I can see the exact problem.

Comment: bootstrap is ot getting supported by fiddle. i'm using bootstrap for CSS

Comment: i found that if i doen't have the href link the active class is working fine. if i have a href link clicking on it takes to another page and jquery is not working. someone kindly help me how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs when you run `jQuery click` event on one page & want to see the changes on other pages, it's not possible. For this issue, jquery will not work properly, you have to write individually `active` class on each page, just like this:

On home page:

```
<li class="active"><a href="home"><span class="gyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> Home</a></li>
<li><a href="about">About</a></li>
<li><a href="contact">Contact</a></li>
```

On about page:

```
<li><a href="home"><span class="gyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> Home</a></li>
<li class="active"><a href="about">About</a></li>
<li><a href="contact">Contact</a></li>
```

On contact page:

```
<li><a href="home"><span class="gyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> Home</a></li>
<li><a href="about">About</a></li>
<li class="active"><a href="contact">Contact</a></li>
```

I hope, this will be helpful for you.

Comment: I have created a single menu page and adding that page to other pages like home, contact and about so i don't have a option to add active class induvidually.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
var selector = '.nav li';
$(selector).on('click', function(){
    $(selector).removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

---

And change the order of js file:

1. jQuery js file
2. bootstrap min.js